# My automatic phonegap installer needs jdk download with wget, I have it working in command prompt but not in .hta file

Tags: scripting, vbscript, wget, hta

I have written a vbscript based .hta installer to install PhoneGap/Cordova automatically with all the pre-requisites(ant/jdk/bada sdk etc). Its almost done but I am stuck at the part where I need to download JDK directly.

**If you copy paste this (long) line in commandprompt and it works**

```
 wget --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html;" ""http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-i586.exe -O jdk.exe
```

It will download JDK directly , absolutely fine .

**When you paste the code snippet in notepad e.g and save as .vbs and run it then it doesnt work**

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.CurrentDirectory = "c:\"

'inQuotes function just puts quotes around the command parameters
objShell.Run inQuotes(WorkingDir & "\wget.exe") & " "  & " --header "  & inQuotes("Cookie: gpw_e24=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html; ") & "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-i586.exe" & " -O" & " "  & inQuotes("jdk.exe"),1,True 


Function inQuotes(toQuote)
    'return with quotes around the toQuote parameter
    inQuotes = chr(34) & toQuote & chr(34)
End Function
```

Somewhere in teh objShell.Run line there is a problem and wget isn't downloading the jdk ...
Will really appreciate any help
thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your variable `WorkingDir` is defined? If I put one echo:

```
strCmd = inQuotes(WorkingDir & "\wget.exe") & " " & " --header " _
& inQuotes("Cookie: gpw_e24=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html; ") _
& "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-i586.exe" & " -O" & " "  & inQuotes("jdk.exe")
WScript.Echo strCmd
```

I get this:

```
"\wget.exe"  --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html; "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-i586.exe -O "jdk.exe"
```

And this not pass to the original command. Maybe it s'd be like this?

```
strCmd = "wget.exe --header " _
& inQuotes("Cookie: gpw_e24=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html;") _
& " " & chr(34) &chr(34) & "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-i586.exe" _
& " -O jdk.exe"
WScript.Echo strCmd
```

Comment: thanks for your time. The working dir variable is right. what I found was that the the script works if i put it in c:\ for example,but doesnt when I put it where the folder has a longer name. in this case my script was at d:\savedfiles\skydrive\desktop\phonegapinstaller and I THINK shell was unable to find it . so i fixed it by using .\ instead of working dir and now it works ! MAGIC :D